# how to upgrade from NODE_MODULE_VERSION 101 to NODE_MODULE_VERSION 102

Tags: node.js, node-canvas

canvas.node
was compiled against a different Node.js version using

```
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 102. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 101. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
```

the module (for instance, using "npm rebuild" or "npm install").
i don't know how to upgrade my node-module-version and don't know how to solve this problem.

please help if you did solve this problem already.

thanks.